# I can not calibrate correct accurate for resistive touch screen on Kivy app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I have a problem with my  5 inch resistive touch screen which I need to calibrate touch on Kivy app. My touch in Raspberry pi is correctly calibrated but when it comes to Kivy app it is not correct.

How can I calibrate the touch to get accurate touch in my Kivy app (GUI). I am using Raspberry pi 3 with Raspbian os (full version not lite) this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the configuration options for Kivy's mtdev input module: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.providers.mtdev.html - in particular max_position_x, min_position_y, etc. From the documentation:

> You can use a custom range for the X, Y and pressure values. On some drivers, the range reported is invalid. To fix that, you can add these options to the argument line:
>
> ```
> invert_x : 1 to invert X axis
> invert_y : 1 to invert Y axis
> min_position_x : X minimum
> max_position_x : X maximum
> min_position_y : Y minimum
> max_position_y : Y maximum
> min_pressure : pressure minimum
> max_pressure : pressure maximum
> min_touch_major : width shape minimum
> max_touch_major : width shape maximum
> min_touch_minor : width shape minimum
> max_touch_minor : height shape maximum
> rotation : 0,90,180 or 270 to rotate
> ```

In ~/.kivy/config.ini, you should put something like this:

```
[input]
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev,max_position_x=12345,max_position_y=12345
```

This is if you're using `mtdev`,  but you can also use `hidinput` from kernel 2.6.34 onwards. See also: https://kivy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-kivy.input.providers.hidinput.html

Comment: How can i change the value of x and y and where to assign it. Can you give detail information please

Comment: The same problem exists the axis is still incorrect. Is there any other solution.